# Please help a newbie with blog page issue?

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

https://diarmuidoconnorbooks.com/home/?p=1561

https://diarmuidoconnorbooks.com/home/?page_id=1355

The first link is to my post’s permalink. The second is at it appears when you go to the website’s blog page from the navigation panel. I have no idea how to make the second link look like the first. It’s really bothering me. I’ve dug around the settings and googled lots, but nothing. Can someone please help?

I’m using Bluehost’s BH Website Builder theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses something called [Post Types](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/) to generate different types of content.

The first URL belongs to a post ( default type ). You can access it under the "Posts" menu.

The seconds URL belongs to a post type called "page", or simply a Page. You can access it under the "Pages" menu.

To achieve what you need, you can make a new post and copy the page's content to it.

A better solution would be to setup pretty permalinks under the "Settings" menu.

Comment: I’m confused by what you mean. The blog “page” has no content other than what has been posted to it. “Blog” is set as my “posts” page.

What kind of permalink would you recommend that could solve the issue? I’d like for this not to be a problem for every blog post I make in the future

Comment: Any pretty permalink will do. You can head over to "Settings > Permalinks" and choose one, and click "Save changes". Take a look at [this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/) page, it explains what a static blog page is.

Comment: I did that but the blog page is still showing “blog” over the image and not the post title. I went through the different options other than plain, and no change.

Comment: I figured something out. Thank you for all your help!